# Power pivot 2013 - group sales values

Tags: excel-2013, powerpivot

I have a powerpivot table of enquiry values and I would like to count how many enquiries in certain value ranges there areie
0 -50000
50001 - 250000
250001 - 500000
500001 - 1000000
1000000+

How can I do this on a power pivot table?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot/example of the data, and how you're imagining the output to look? Visuals will help

Comment: Range 0-50000   50001-250000  250001-500000  500001-1000000

Comment: It won't let me post a visual I'm afraid.   the ranges above with a count of the number of transactions with a value that fall within those ranges